# TimeZone in SmartGwt

Tags: java, smartgwt

I want to provide TimeZone settings in application, So, I need to get the Time Zones from the browser using smart Gwt. Please tell me the methods for getting time zones. Actually I have written java coding in smart gwt application as follows,

```
String timezones[]=java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

for(int i=0;i<(timezones.length)-1;i++)
{

System.out.println(timezones[i]);

}
```

but it is not worked out and it is throwing an Exception as follows:

1. `[ERROR] [timezoneproject] Line 32: No source code is available for type java.util.TimeZone; did you forget to inherit a required module`
2. `[ERROR] [timezoneproject] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

GWT do support TimeZone.

Refer the com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZoneConstants interface for list for TimeZones

can be found [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/constants/TimeZoneConstants.html)

Also Find the Test program [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/TimeZoneTest.java?r=3655)

TO Create Timezone in GWT

```
final TimeZoneConstants timeZoneConstants = GWT.create(TimeZoneConstants.class);

TimeZone usPacific = TimeZone.createTimeZone(
        TimeZoneInfo.buildTimeZoneData(timeZoneConstants.americaLosAngeles()));
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jean-Michel Garcia said, you cannot run the TimeZone class methods on the client side of your GWT application.

Instead, you should call `String timezones[]=java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();` on the server-side of GWT and return the string array to the client and then do whatever you want with it

Comment: @user1438970 can you please accept the answer which helped you?

Answer (score 0):

TimeZone is not part of the GWT emulated JRE. Therefore, you can't use it.

Please see this link : https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_util